# JS HTML Canvas, get coordinates shows a static float in the x coordinate

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mouse-position

I have a canvas on an html page, and I'm using the sample code from https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-mouse-coordinates/.

The x coordinate is showing with a decimal of .78125

```
Mouse position: 239.78125,455
Mouse position: 239.78125,453
Mouse position: 240.78125,452
Mouse position: 240.78125,451
Mouse position: 241.78125,450
Mouse position: 241.78125,448
```

The coordinates appear to be correct other than the decimal.

I'm not sure what would be causing this, any suggestions on how to fix?

---

The coordinates should look like this

```
Mouse position: 239,455
Mouse position: 239,453
Mouse position: 240,452
Mouse position: 240,451
Mouse position: 241,450
Mouse position: 241,448
```

But there is some bug that is causing the coordinates to become floats.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: Use `math.round` to turn a decimal into an integer...?

Comment: `Element.getBoudingClientRect` returns a [DOMRect](https://drafts.fxtf.org/geometry-1/#domrect) which attributes are doubles (float), no surprises here.